# C'è una differenza tra "onestamente" e "francamente"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

Sto imparando delle nuove parole con frasi esemplari.

Nel caso di **onestamente** ho la frase seguente:

> "Onestamente non so se Luca ha ragione. Non credo."

Esiste una differenza tra le parole **onestamente** e **francamente**? Potete darmi alcuni esempi?

Grazie!

Comment: Potresti contestualizzare un minimo la tua richiesta?

Comment: Scusa, certo: Imparo delle nuove parole con delle frasi esemplari. Nel caso di "onestamente" ho la frase seguente: "Onestamente non so se Luca ha ragione. Non credo." Con la tua spiegazione sotto, penso che in questo caso sarebbero corette le due parole.

Comment: Nel caso da te citato puoi usare anche francamente:"**Francamente** non so se Luca ha ragione. Non credo."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Un buon punto di partenza potrebbe essere la definizione di Treccani per [onestamente](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/onestamente_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/):

> **onestamente** /onesta'mente/ avv. [der. di onesto, col suff. -mente]. -
>   1. [secondo moralità e rettitudine: vivere o.] ≈ con onestà, lealmente, rettamente. ↔ disonestamente, slealmente. 2. (ant.) [con
>   decoro e decenza: Come 'l candido piè per l'erba fresca Dolci passi o.
>   move (F. Petrarca)] ≈ decorosamente. ↔ indecentemente,
>   indecorosamente. 3. [con valore frasale, in verità, per essere
>   franchi: o., non era una proposta accettabile; di questo, o., non ho
>   parlato; io avrei rifiutato l'offerta, o.] ≈ **francamente**, in
>   coscienza, in tutta franchezza (o onestà), sinceramente, veramente.

e per [francamente](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/francamente_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/):

> **francamente** /franka'mente/ avv. [der. di franco², col suff. -mente]. - 1. [con franchezza, con schiettezza: ti dirò f. ciò che ne penso] ≈ apertamente, chiaramente, chiaro e tondo, franco, (fam.) in
>   faccia, onestamente, schiettamente, sinceramente. ↔ ambiguamente,
>   falsamente, ipocritamente, subdolamente. 2. [come avv. frasale, per
>   introdurre una frase con valore leggermente avversativo o per
>   puntualizzare: f. non mi pare] ≈ a dire il vero (o la verità), in
>   realtà, in verità, **onestamente**, per la precisione (o l'esattezza).

Come puoi vedere si possono considerare sinonimi, anche se, a mio parere, in alcuni casi si preferisce l'una all'altra.
Ad esempio:

> I miei genitori mi hanno insegnato a comportarmi ***onestamente*** (qui francamente stonerebbe)

oppure

> La pressione fiscale nel nostro sgangherato Paese ha raggiunto livelli
>   ***francamente*** intollerabili. (qui stesso discorso di prima)

Ad inizio frase io utilizzerei francamente invece di onestamente, ma, ripeto, questa è una preferenza personale.

Altri esempi di frasi con [francamente](http://www.dizy.com/it/voce/francamente/frasi) e [onestamente](http://www.dizy.com/it/voce/onestamente/frasi).

Comment: Grazie per la tua spiegazione! Le darei un "upvote" ma non posso perché non ho ancora abbastanza reputazione su italian.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Essendo colui che ha posto la domanda puoi accettarla spuntando il simbolo a sinistra sotto al numero degli upvote, guadagnando +2 punti. Appena raggiungi i 15 punti potrai effettuare l'upvote. Per info leggi la sezione [privileges](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

Comment: Fatto! Grazie! :-)